# else part doesn't work in php script

Tags: php

In the following php script when correct un and pass were given, it displays Welcome.But when we give wrong pass as shown in the code, it doesn't output "Wrong username password combination".what is the reason for that?

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$query)
{
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}
if (mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row   = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    if ($row['un'] == $un && $row['pd'] == $encpass)
    {
        echo "<h1>WellCome</h1>";
        echo '<br /><a href="home.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
        echo $row['un'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong user name password combination";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: please indent your code. You can use tools [like this](http://beta.phpformatter.com/) if your code really does look like that.

Answer (score 2):

$Since you check for the right password in the select there will not be any row to fetch if the password is wrong, therefore you will not enter the code after mysql_fetch_assoc.

Try

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo "<h1>WellCome</h1>";
  echo '<br /><a href="home.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
  echo $row['un'];
} else {
  echo "Wrong user name password combination";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
...
if(mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if($row['un'] == $un && $row['pd'] == $encpass) {
    echo "<h1>WellCome</h1>";
    echo '<br /><a href="home.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
    echo $row['un'];
} else
    echo "Wrong user name password combination";
} else
echo "Wrong user name password combination";
...
```